# How to use global matching with multiple capture groups?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use a regexp that contains multiple capture groups in a global search. The regex is input by the user, so I do not know the number of capture groups in advance. For each application of the regex, I would like to store the current matches in an array. Here is a simple example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my $str = 'Name: John Smith, Name: Bill Gates';

pos($str) = 0;
while (1) {

    #Note: the regex is not known at compile time
    my @a = $str =~ /\GName: (\w+) (\w+)/;
    dd @a;
    last if @a == 0; 
    pos($str) = $+[0];
}
```

However, this does not work. The output is:

> ("John", "Smith")

Expected output would be:

> ("John", "Smith")
>   ("Bill", "Gates")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I just forgot a `.*?` to skip from the `\G` anchor to the next match:

```
my @a = $str =~ /\G.*?Name: (\w+) (\w+)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use global regex in perl you simply put a 'g' at the end like this: `$str =~ /REGEX/g;`

So you should change the regex line to be `my @a = $str =~ /Name: (\w+) (\w+)/g;` and you should get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of the `g` operator.. Using that I would get all matches at once. Sorry, this was not my intention, I would like to get each set of matches in groups. One group for each iteration of the while loop..

Comment: Ah okay. That may be possible with only regex but you could just split the string by a comma and do it that way.

Comment: Yes for this simple case, but in my actual situation, the string does not necessary contain commas. For example the string could be random file contents, and the user inputs both the file name and the regex..

Answer (score 0):

from the input string which contains optional commas as separator, I have obtained this output ("John Smith", "Bill Gates", "Mark Twain") with this simple script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my $str = 'Name: John Smith, Name: Bill Gates Name: Mark Twain';

my @person = split (/Name:/, $str);
my @a;

foreach (@person) { 
    s/\,//; # trim comma
    s/^\s+//; # trim leading space
    s/\s+$//; # trim trailing space
    s/Name:\s(\w+) (\[^,]+)/$1 $2/;
    if ($_ ne "") {push @a, $_;}
};

dd @a;
```

Comment: Nice, but I am afraid this does not meet the requirements I had in mind.. The names in `$str` was just a sample, the string does not have to contain names at all, it could be a Perl source file for example. I was trying to simplify the general case, by showing a specific case.. sorry if that was confusing..